# Reading files using Python

Tags: python, file, function

I have a file of the following format.

```
"08-10-2010 13:29:31      1 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:29:31      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:29:31      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -80"
"08-10-2010 13:30:32      2 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:30:32      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:30:32      00:1e:79:d7:d5:40                                 -93"
"08-10-2010 13:30:32      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -78"
"08-10-2010 13:31:33      2 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:31:33      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:31:33      00:1e:79:d7:d5:40                                 -94"
"08-10-2010 13:31:33      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -79"
"08-10-2010 13:32:34      1 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:32:34      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:32:34      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -94"
"08-10-2010 13:33:35      1 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:33:35      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:33:35      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -88"
"08-10-2010 13:34:36      1 APs were seen
"
"08-10-2010 13:34:36      MAC Address         SSID                          RSSI"
"08-10-2010 13:34:36      00:1e:79:d7:d5:b0                                 -82"
```

As you can see from the copied text, at every instant of time, a computer might see 1 or 2 or 3 (or maybe more) number of APs. I need to create the following file: 
1. The file will have a date and time (specified as a datetime object). It needs to go and check the file and return the MAC addresses of the two [AP](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/access_point)s which have the highest [RSSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) values.

Now as you can see from the file at some times the computer will see only one AP. In that case the function has to return the MAC address of that AP, and "none" as the second return value. When there are more than two APs recorded at that time, then it has to return the highest two.

How would I do this?

Comment: Post what you have so far and what doesn't work

Comment: I didn't see anything from reading the copied text because it is poorly formatted and I don't want to put that much effort into it. And BTW, when somebody answers your question, you will see a checkmark under the vote count. When somebody gives you the 'best' answer, you click the checkmark and the person gets 15 rep. It's a considerate thing to do.

Comment: Perhaps you should accept some of the answers to your questions as well.  Having 0/5 accepted answers doesn't look to good for you.

Comment: hello aaron, thanks for letting me know. i wasnt aware, have updated.

Comment: Looking at all the questions you've asked so far it seems like you're trying to get others to do your work for you. Are you passing along homework?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/

Look carefully at sections 10 and 7. They will give you what you need to look at a file and parse it for the information required. Study, post something, whether it works or not, and we'll help you out more.